# Create excel chart using Interop - Error when update to Office 2013

Tags: c#, excel, interop

We have an application that exports a sheet with data and and graph based on this data.

Everything works fine on Office 2010. When some users starts to upgrade their Office package to 2013 version, the application stop working.

Debugging i could get the exact point was the error is happening.

```
SeriesCollection series = chartPage.SeriesCollection();
Series serie = series.NewSeries(); // Error happens here!
```

The error is: return argument has an invalid type!

What am i missing? Thanks for any help!

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22777112/how-generate-chart-from-excel-sheet-using-c-sharp-interop

Answer (score 0):

It is likely having a problem resolving the proper version of the interop assembly. Try going to the reference and changing `Specific Version` to `True` on the reference properties. Clean your solution and rebuild. You can also ensure that the `Embed Interop Types` is set to `True`.

You can also remove the old interop reference and re-reference to version 15 of interops.

Comment: The Specific Version property is not available for interop assemblies.

Comment: @FabioKobuti That property is available for Interop Library References. It would not be available for Project References though. What is the name of the reference you are modifying the properties on? And if you view it in Object Browser, do you see multiple instances of it?

Comment: No, there's only one... But with the link above, i was able to generate correctly... The problem is, i have 3 series on chart, with chart wizard i can only put one. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found a "workaround" to solve this. If you insert with SeriesCollection.Add method, works fine. The problem still exists, but with a way to fixit.