# How to export a chart.js chart to excel?

Tags: javascript, excel, chart.js

I am using a chart.js 2 javascript chart in a web application and so far it has been great, but is there a way to export the data into an excel or pdf file ? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could collect all data related to your chart and send this data as Json via Ajax to some controller. Then just draw it, similar post can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22777112/how-generate-chart-from-excel-sheet-using-c-sharp-interop)

Answer (score 1):

Excel does not recognize the chart. I think the chart should be turned into an image. Then you need to export an image to excel. This page can help you : https://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/f/ignite-ui-for-javascript/109480/adding-image-in-excel