# export chart.js graphics to Json or Excel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, chart.js

I'm building an website and i'm using chart.js to build my graphics.

I wanted to know if it is possible export the data to json or even better to Excel.
I have looked for everywhere for help but i got nothing.

Is this possible?
If it is please give me some advice...or help...

The language that I'm working is php, js and jquery.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How generate chart from Excel sheet using c# interop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22777112/how-generate-chart-from-excel-sheet-using-c-sharp-interop)

Comment: Well that is in C# and i dont really understand, but the question is similar.

Comment: Just grab onto the JSON, which is the point of the article I think.

Comment: Well the point of article is Excel but if its not possible i think its to JSON but i dont know how, and i think that i can convert json to excel no?