# Is there a way to create a chart in Excel if I have the chart.xml file?

Tags: excel, interop, powerpoint, excel-interop

I need to create a chart in my AddIn (COM, not VSTO). I already have code that creates the chart.xml file (I use it in our Word AddIn calling Range.InsertXML() to add a chart in Word.

Does Excel have this? And if not, is there sample code in C# showing how to programmatically add a chart from an AddIn?

**One key point** - we pass literal data to the chart, not a range in a worksheet. [So all the examples showing how to do this that I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22777112/how-generate-chart-from-excel-sheet-using-c-sharp-interop) - not what I need.

And same question for PowerPoint. - Does it have this capability?

thanks - dave

Comment: A Google search for *Excel Object Model* would be extremely useful in answering these sorts of simple questions. Change *Excel* to *Powerpoint* for the second search.

Comment: As Ken suggests, or start Excel or PPT, ALT+F11 to go to the IDE, F2 to open the Object Browser and search for InsertXML. Occasionally some members of the object model will be hidden but usable; to see them, right click the "Members of ..." pane and choose Show Hidden Members. It might be chancy to use an objects that then show up; your call.

Comment: @KenWhite - Unfortunately all the examples are around using a worksheet for the data instead of assigning literal data. Do you know of any examples showing how to do this with literal data?

Comment: @SteveRindsberg - I looked for an equivalent to InsertXML() years ago. Couldn't find it. And a Product Manager on the Excel team confirmed for me that Excel has no equivalent to that.

Comment: If an Excel Product Manager has already confirmed for you that Excel doesn't have this, then why does your question ask *Does Excel have this?*

Comment: @KenWhite Because I had another product manager, and two developers on the Excel team insist that you can't have literal data in a chart.xml file for a chart. Yet you can. So I figure always good to ask again.